# Horizontal parallax on touch devices

Tags: jquery, ipad, parallax

I need a horizontal parallax scroll to work on touch devices. I am making a game where you will be able to scroll sideways only. I need a couple of layers (at least three) that will move in diffrent paces.
I have tried a couple of plugins (jInvertScroll and Stellar.js to name a few) but can't get it to work. Is there a simple way to do this from scratch?

EDIT: Can't get Stellar.js to work. This is the snippet:
I assume that Stellar finds the objects and moves them accordingly since two boxes have display:none; at start. And that they get absolute positioning. But they don't move. At this stage I just want them to move.
And, what steps do I need to take to have this effect on an iPad/tablet.

jQuery libraries:

```
<script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<!-- OWN JQUERY -->
<script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#parallaxElements').stellar({
    horizontalScrolling: true
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- PICTURES AND LAYERS -->
<div id="content">
    <div id="parallaxElements">
        <div id="forgrund" class="frontdrop" data-stellar-ratio="2" style="background:tomato;width:200px;height:50px;">
        </div>

        <div id="kullarna" class="middledrop" data-stellar-ratio="1" style="background:purple;width:200px;height:50px;">
        </div>

        <div id="bg" class="backdrop" data-stellar-ratio="0.5" style="background:blue;width:200px;height:50px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content{
    position:relative;
    width:1024px;
    height:768px;
    background-color:gray;
    overflow:scroll;
}
#bg, #kullarna, #forgrund{
    width:2050px;
    position:absolute;
}
#bg{
    height:768px;
}
#kullarna{
    z-index:10;
}
#forgrund{
    z-index:11;
    height:600px;
}
```

Comment: There is no simple CSS or JS methods, elements, or properties that enable easy implementation of parallaxing. They all rely on fixing the background element in CSS, and using JS to regulate the movement of the foreground layers in varying proportions to the scroll action. Plugins are often the way to go here unfortunately. If you can define the problems you are having with implementing one of your plugin options as a fiddle, we can likely help you get that working properly.

Comment: I have updated my post with a snippet code. And as I stated in the EDIT-text. I just want it to move and know what steps I need to take to make it work on tablets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this plugin! http://robbiestewart.ca/wordpress/parallaxSwipe/parallax.html
It works great!
It has both vertical parallax and horizontal (the horizontal is wrongly named though "parallaxVertical.js").